# Having trouble getting submitted values and names in dynamic radio button loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, radio-button

I have selected data from mysql and inserted them into a radio button form which is looped as shown:

```
if($num_rows) {

    echo '<form name="fixtureform" method="POST" action="index.php">';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo $row["home_team"] . " vs " . $row["away_team"]. '<br />' . " Home" . '<input type="radio" name="win'.$row["home_id"].'" value="'.$row["home_id"].'"/>' ." Draw" . '<input type="radio" name="'.$row["home_id"].$row["away_id"].'" value="draw"/>' ." Away" . '<input type="radio" name="win'.$row["away_id"].'" value="' . $row["away_id"] . '"/>' .'<br />';

}
    echo '<input type="Submit" Name="Submitacc" Value="Submit your teams">';
    echo '</form>';

} else { 
        echo "There are no fixtures today ";
        }
```

I then have an if statement for submitted values:

```
if($_POST['Submitacc']=='Submit your teams') {


    }
```

How would I say if the selected name of the radio button is win.$row[home_id] - insert value into mysql table. I'm struggling with the fact I can't get $row[home_id] outside of the loop?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below

```
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["home_team"] . " vs " . $row["away_team"]. '<br />' . " Home" . '<input type="radio" name="result['.$i.']" value="h_'.$row["home_id"].'"/>' ." Draw" . '<input type="radio" name="result['.$i.']" value="draw"/>' ." Away" . '<input type="radio" name="result['.$i.']" value="a_' . $row["away_id"] . '"/>' .'<br />';
  $i++;
}
```

In Your PHP

```
foreach($_POST['result'] as $value){
   if($value == 'draw') {
     //do stuff
   }
   else {
     $apart = explode('_',$value);
     if($apart[0]=='h'){
        //home team win
        echo $apart[1];
     }
     else {
        //away team win
        echo $apart[1];          
     }
   } 
}
```

Comment: I think this looks like the most viable option, thanks a lot :)

Comment: One more thing sorry, where could I put my match_id in the radio button, so I could extract that in the foreach loop?

Comment: what is `match_id` ? is it `0,1,2...` ?

Comment: match_id is from my mysql database so $row["match_id"] - I've put it in the value and then used if(strstr($value, 'draw')) and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
echo"<input name='win' type='radio' value='".$row['home_id']."' />";
```

Comment: when I had all my input names as the same in the loop such as 'homewin' 'draw' 'awaywin' the loop wouldn't let me select say a 'homewin' one row and a 'homewin' the next

Comment: give same name to each radio button group like <input type='radio' name='gender' value='male' />male<input type='radio' name='gender' value='female' />female

Comment: if you want to choose one answer out of a bunch of radio button then you have to use same name for all buttons of that radio group but the values will be different.(You can use different id, but name should be same)

Answer (score 0):

Because your radios have different names they are all separate and all being submitted, I recommend naming them all "result" and giving them values of "win", "draw" and "loose" respectively.

```
<label>Win: <input type="radio" name="result" value="win" /></label>
<label>Draw: <input type="radio" name="result" value="draw" /></label>
<label>Loose: <input type="radio" name="result" value="loose" /></label>
<input type="hidden" name="home_team" value="<?php echo $row['home_team']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="away_team" value="<?php echo $row['away_team']; ?>" />
```

You can access the value with $_POST['result'] and since you know the home team and away team you can handle the data accordingly

Comment: why would I have hidden input types?

Comment: Just to pass the home_team and away_team values through your $_POST data, you wouldn't necessarily have to do it this way it's just one method

Answer (score 0):

Change your element name to `win.home` without the `id`, since you will get it by the value.

Then go like:

```
if(isset($_POST['win.home'])) { }
```

---

Edit:

If you want to do it like this, try this:

3 radio buttons, named `win.home`, `draw`, `win.away` plus a unique id (mysql id?) like `win.home.1234` then you can use as many games as you want. You can get the id back with `explode()` later.

Then the values:

1st: `$row["home_id"] . "-" . $row["away_id"]`

2nd: `draw`

3rd: `$row["away_id"] . "-" . $row["home_id"]`

Then when processing the form:

Split the value with `explode()` at the `-`. So the first id is always the winner.

Comment: if I do this and say do this: if(isset($_POST['win.name'])) {
 
 $win=$_POST('win.name');
 
 echo $win;

Comment: sorry, this see nothing when I print it

Answer (score 0):

i think a diferent usage of the radio button mechanic shuold be used in this case.

in your example you are creating 3 diferent instances of a radio button for each row, instead create one instance of a radio button set with diferent values depending on the answer given

like:

```
<input type="radio" name="game'.$row["game_id"].'" value="'.$row["home_id"].'">
<input type="radio" name="game'.$row["game_id"].'" value="draw">
<input type="radio" name="game'.$row["game_id"].'" value="'.$row["away_id"].'">
```

this means that the variable `$_POST["game1"]` will have the value of the winner or draw that was selected for game which is `game_id 1`

hope this helps you